# How can I work around Excel crashing with certain SELECT statements?

Tags: sql, vba, oracle, excel, ado

These two statements are similar but the second causes Excel to crash every time it is execute. The only difference is between `model` and `model return updated rows` (I've specially designed this minimal example so that the queries return exactly the same data in either case, my real-world SQL is different of course):

1. ```sql
   select *
   from( select *
         from ( select 1 id, 100 val from dual
                union all 
                select 2 id, 200 val from dual )
         model
         dimension by (id)
         measures (val)
         rules ( val[1] = val[cv()]+1 ) )
   where val=101
   ```
2. ```sql
   select *
   from( select *
         from ( select 1 id, 100 val from dual
                union all 
                select 2 id, 200 val from dual )
         model return updated rows
         dimension by (id)
         measures (val)
         rules ( val[1] = val[cv()]+1 ) )
   where val=101
   ```

Is this an isolated example of a bug in ADO or is there a known class of SQL statements that crash the parser (I'm not even sure why ADO would parse the statement rather than just passing it through to the database).

Here's the VBA code in full for the version that crashes:

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Go()

    Dim lConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim lRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    'Dim lRecordset
    Dim sSQL As String

    Set lConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set lRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    'Set lRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    lConn.Open "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=GTU_APP)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=devdb)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=oracle)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id=csuk;Password=thisisnotmyrealpassword;"

    With lRecordset
        sSQL = "select * " & _
               "from( select * " & _
               "      from ( select 1 id, 100 val from dual " & _
               "             Union all " & _
               "             select 2 id, 200 val from dual ) " & _
               "      model return updated rows " & _
               "      dimension by(id) " & _
               "      measures (val) " & _
               "      rules ( val[1] = val[cv()]+1 ) ) " & _
               "where val=101"
        .Open sSQL, lConn
        While Not .EOF
            Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = ![Val]
            .MoveNext
        Wend
        .Close
    End With

    Set lRecordset = Nothing
    lConn.Close
    Set lConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

In response to a comment, I've tried that same SQL using DAO, and to my bafflement, we get the same result. The following code crashes Excel, but removing the `return updated rows` is all it takes to make it work as expected:

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Go()

    Dim lWorkspace As DAO.Workspace
    Dim lDatabase As DAO.Database
    Dim lRecordset As DAO.Recordset

    Dim sSQL As String

    sSQL = "select * " & _
           "from( select * " & _
           "      from ( select 1 id, 100 val from dual " & _
           "             Union all " & _
           "             select 2 id, 200 val from dual ) " & _
           "      model return updated rows " & _
           "      dimension by(id) " & _
           "      measures (val) " & _
           "      rules ( val[1] = val[cv()]+1 ) ) " & _
           "where val=101"

    Set lWorkspace = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    Set lDatabase = lWorkspace.OpenDatabase("", False, False, "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=devdb:1521/oracle;Uid=charts_csuk_uksoft;Pwd=thisisnotmyrealpassword;")
    Set lRecordset = lDatabase.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSQLPassThrough)

    With lRecordset
        While Not .EOF
            Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = ![Val]
            .MoveNext
        Wend
    End With

    Set lRecordset = Nothing
    Set lDatabase = Nothing
    Set lWorkspace = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: add `Set lConn = Nothing` below `lConn.Close` to free linkage to the connection. Now, does Excel crash with the late binding of the ADODB.Recordset too? Also see this [tip](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?511763-Classic-VB-Why-shouldn-t-I-use-quot-Dim-As-New-quot) relating to using `As New`. How about using ADODB alternatives? Let us know if any of these help

Comment: Thanks, I've tried adding `set lConn = Nothing` and updated the question with that improvement. I've also tried late binding (see commented lines in edited question. Neither of these prevent the crash, I'd be interested to know what ADODB alternatives you'd suggest trying?

Comment: The first one I can think of is [DAO](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html). Another option would be to write your own COM library using C# or VB.NET and add references to your `dll` (same as adding any other references i.e. Microsoft Scripting Library). Using a COM library allows you to create your own objects of your own type in Excel. Said that it would allow you to pass queries directly to the COM library which would execute it against your database skipping the ADODB parser etc. You would use the `SQL Connection` from the `System.Data.SqlClient` library.

Comment: It's not as hard as it sounds and I am sure you can easily get it done with the help of SO. The bad site of this alternative is that you would have to provide the `dll` to anyone who is using your spreadsheet. If you are the only person then that would not be a problem, but if you share the spreadsheet then all users would need the `dll`. If you decide to go in that direction then edit your question a bit so I can give you a C# answer to how to create a COM library etc.

Comment: Have you tried to hide statements, upsetting Excel, behind `VIEW`?

Comment: @mehow you are far to kind to offer to help like that, thank you. I don't think it is a route I can go down though as the workarounds I already know about are probably easier in our environment.

Comment: @JackDouglas To go further with a workaround (if no other option left), you may write a procedure(s), creating(destroying) that views using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to mask your behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a workaround, than solution, but it might be an option to hide any SQL statements, upsetting ADO (or Excel, for that matter), behind `VIEW`. For dynamic statements (i.e. changing views in run time) you might consider using procedures with [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ...`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm) in them.

Comment: This is roughly what I've done, thanks. ADO seems quite happy with `lConn.Execute "create view v_sidNNN as " & sSQL"` and `select * from v_sidNNN`.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the troublesome syntax by building a custom version of `return updated rows`.

Add a fake column to track what has been updated, and initialize it to false (0).  Then add a measure, and for each rule create a similar rule that will set the flag to true (1).  Finally, add a predicate to only include rows where the flag is 1.

This is clearly not an ideal solution.  It will be slower.  And you must remember to build
all the extra rules that populate the flag.

```
select id, val
from( select *
      from ( select 1 id, 100 val, 0 is_updated_or_inserted from dual
             union all 
             select 2 id, 200 val, 0 is_updated_or_inserted from dual 
             union all 
             select 3 id, 101 val, 0 is_updated_or_inserted from dual )
      model
      dimension by (id)
      measures (val, is_updated_or_inserted)
      rules ( val[1] = val[cv()]+1 , is_updated_or_inserted[1] = 1) )
where val=101
  and is_updated_or_inserted = 1
```

---

**Update**

Here are a few more ideas.

1. Can you switch to Oracle's software?  Your first subroutine works for me if I use `Provider=ORAOLEDB.ORACLE`.  And your second subroutine works if I use an Oracle DSN.  I can't get `MSDAORA` or `{Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}` to connect at all on my machine.  (Although that's probably my fault.)
2. Try changing `model return updated rows` to `model keep nav return updated rows main main_model`.  This is a semantically meaningless change, it just
   explicitly lists the defaults.  But perhaps it's enough to avoid the parsing bug you're running into.

Comment: I was already aware I can work around it like this, but I appreciate the effort, thanks. You probably know this but you don't need to add `is_updated_or_inserted` to the source table, you [can just add it to the measures](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/15863).

Comment: Good suggestions, I've already tried playing around inserting comments inside the `return updated rows` clause but neither that or the full `keep nav return updated rows main main_model` text has any effect. We don't currently have the Oracle provider installed in our environment to test. I've reached the stage where I think I will go with a workaround: probably creating and dropping views with the sid in the name.